# python FTP error when dowloading all files in a list

Tags: download, ftplib

does someone know why python is not downloading all the files in the list below? The first file downloads and then i get an 'error2' for the second file.

```
fdnload1 = ['AAA092214.TXT', '092214 REPORT TOTALS.TXT']
try:
    # DOWNLOAD FILES
    for fdn in fdnload1:
        ftrans1 = open(fdn,'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fdn, ftrans1.write)
        print 'Downloading...' + fdn
except:
    print 'error2'
```

results:

```
Downloading...AAA092214.TXT
error2
```

when i run the program without actually downloading the files, it iterates through all files:

```
try:
    # DOWNLOAD FILES
    for fdn in fdnload1:
        print 'Downloading...' + fdn
except:
    print 'error2'
```

results:

```
Downloading...AAA092214.TXT
Downloading...092214 REPORT TOTALS.TXT
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

E D I T # 1: 
i was able to get all files in `fdnload1` to download by creating a separate function to download files, but i am still getting errors, and they are coming from the actual download process (see my results are printing 'error in download1() function'. does anyone know why?

also, i just checked the files that were downloaded and they are empty, so they did not actually download properly...

```
def download1(fdn):
    os.chdir('C:/directory10')
    try:
        ftrans1 = open(fdn,'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fdn, ftrans1.write)
        print 'file: ' + fdn + 'download complete...'
    except:
        print 'error in download1() function'
```

modified the original code to run the `download()` function:

```
try:
    # DOWNLOAD FILES
    for fdn in fdnload1:
        print 'Downloading... ' + fdn
        download1(fdn)
except:
    print 'error2'
```

results:

```
Downloading... AAA092214.TXT
error in download1() function
Downloading... 092214 REPORT TOTALS.TXT
error in download1() function
```

Answer (score 0):

it was user permissions error on the ftp side.

ftplib.error_perm: 550 AASN092214.PCI: Permission denied.

logged in under superuser and i was able to download all files with and without the download1() function...

thanks

Comment: you should mark this answer as the 'correct' answer w/ the check button on the left side of it